# Ingress is not working with ELB and route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have an web application deployed on EKS cluster using deployment. POD is getting deployed properly and is in running state. Have created the service of type loadbalancer.
created ingress and ingressclassname .

below are all definition files

1: Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oe-pod-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: oe-pod-ingressclass
  rules:
  - host: "dobby.abc.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: oe-pod-service-loadbalancer
            port:
              number: 4444
```

2: ingressclass

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: oe-pod-ingressclass
spec:
  controller: nginx.org/ingress-controller
```

3: `kubectl get ingress -A`

```
NAMESPACE   NAME             CLASS                 HOSTS                     ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
default     oe-pod-ingress   oe-pod-ingressclass   dobby.abc.com             80      16h
```

4:

```
kubectl get service oe-pod-service-loadbalancer

NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP
PORT(S)          AGE
oe-pod-service-loadbalancer   LoadBalancer   10.2.173.205   <string>.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   4444:32144/TCP   46h
```

have created the route 53 entry for A record and routed the traffic to ELB

still now when Im hitting URL "dobby.abc.com" it is not working . Not sure , what is missing . Please suggest

**UPDATE 1 :**

The security group of EC2 instances which are registered in ELB have the source entry as ELB. It means , EC2 instances are receiving traffic from ELB. However , I see that in ELB , the instances are out of service with reason (**Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively**.)

I think the issue is, in the `kubectl get ingress -A` , the HOSTS and ADDRESS are not mapped properly. please suggest

Comment: "it is not working" meaning what? What issue specifically are you having?

Comment: the specific issue is the URL, "dobby.abc.com" is not accessible/working . I'm not sure what is the issue

Comment: please suggest. I'm stuck .

Comment: try to use the aws-loadbalancer-controller, that have native integration with eks, its more easy for you I guess. rather than using nginx